# DRF setting fields with non string

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

lest say we have a code like this.

```
class UserProfileDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('userThumbnail', 'point')
```

what i want to do is not using `('userThumbnail', 'point')`

but something like this `(nameof(UserProfile.userThumbnail), nameof(UserProfile.point))`

so i don't have to rewrite those fields everytime i rename those.

how can i do something like that?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

```
def nameof(field):
    return field.field_name

class User(models.Model):
    git = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

>>> nameof(User.git)
'git'
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'field_name'` this error come up..//  are you sure field_name is working on python3?